# MVC Resource file non language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resource-file

I have a MVC webapplication where two brands of the same company can login. Both companys have the same language but there are some small words that needs to be changed in the application self.

So my idea is to switch (based on company value) the resource file, but i can't find a solution for this problem.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder for each company and put in each a 'translations.config' file. You can then add keys for each of the phrases that the individual companies want different. You can indicate which folder to look in in web.config.

You will then translate using the global/local resx file you currently have and also lookup your translation in the config file if the folder is set and the file exists.

Comment: So my web.config decides where to look in The folder, is iT company 1 or 2. I dont understood the second part do you have an example or link with more info?